# Google Cloud Deploying Containers VM "Command" option

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I want to create a VM on Google Cloud that runs my docker container. My image is in Google's Artifact Registry and I am able to deploy it to a VM, but it won't allow network requests, even locally (I tried `curl` from the SSH locally and it won't work). The container is a simple Node.js app that returns "Hi there" to any request.

I think the problem is specifying the ports when I create my container / run the image. When creating the container on my local command line, I simply use the `-p` operator to publish ports to the container. But since Google's VM's takes an image from the Artifact Registry and automatically creates a container when it builds the VM, there is no step for me to run the `-p` tag.

I think the solution may have to do with the "Command" option in the Cloud Console (see below) but the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#console_6) make it seem like this has to do with the "Entrypoint" of the app rather than options for creating the container. How do I customize container creation to allow for publishing ports while deploying images to a Google Cloud VM?

[image]

EDIT: Logs

Ok, the logs were more interesting than I thought.
I was right that originally a docker container was created.

[image]

But this container was soon deleted, and new one appeared with a different id that restarted itself every so often.

[image]

EDIT 2:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /untitled
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . ./
CMD node server.js
```

My project is named "untitled." This is a test image just to get everything working.

The actual Node.js code is this:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hi there!")
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening On Port 3000"))
```

And my Package.json is

```
{
  "name": "untitled",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2"
  }
}
```

I'm sure there's something wrong with what I'm doing but I doubt it's the source code--it doesn't exit when I run a local docker container.

Comment: Your container should not exit. COS will restart the container. This means you have something wrong with your container. Edit your question and show the Dockerfile and application. Your container application should be designed to run without exiting. If it is exiting, log the reason why so that you can debug the problem. Also, read the documentation on COS so that you know the difference between how COS runs containers and how Docker does it.

Comment: What is COS and where's the docs for it?

Comment: COS is what you are running - Compute Engine Container Optimized OS. Before using any cloud service, review the pricing and the service's documentation.

Comment: Could the exit issue have to do with the "Command" option in the Google Console? I've tried entering different things in that field, such as "docker run node-test-image" (my image) and "docker run -p 80:3000 node-test-image" so that's where I think the error is

Comment: Edit your question with details on how you are running the container. For COS you don't normally use "docker run" and you definitely don't use the -p (port) option. For regular Compute Engine, you can. Edit your question to clearly define what you are doing and what the problem is. Invest 30 minutes and read the documentation on how to deploy containers.

Comment: Ok, here is the *exact* process I'm using. 

1. Create VM using Google Cloud Console.
2. In "Deploy Container" section, add URL to my image stored in Artifact Registry
3. Allow HTTP and HTTPs for VM.
4. Create VM.
5. SSH to `docker ps` and `docker logs`

Comment: @JohnHanley I've invested far more than 30 minutes reading docs and trying to figure this out. I'm sure you've had a long day but I'm just trying to figure this out. If the docs were so clear I wouldn't be here. This is my third question about basically the same question and I still haven't fixed it. Do you really think I ask questions here for fun? Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I'm just trying to  figure it out and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC using `gcloud compute create-with-container` binds the container to the host's network. So, **any** ports exposed by the container should be available  on the (same) port on the host.

Can you confirm that your container is running on the VM? SSH in and then `docker container ls` (as you would locally).

Can you provide more information on your `curl` command and the response.

You should be able to `sudo journalctl` the VM to review its startup and identify any issues that it had starting the container. You may want to review `konlet-startup` and `docker` units specifically, e.g. `sudo journalctl --unit=konlet-startup` and eyeball whether it starts a container (hopefully your container [ID]).

Another thing to try is to `ss` the VM's (tcp listening) ports. One of these should match your container:

```sh
sudo ss --tcp --listening --processes
```

###### Update

```sh
PROJECT=...
ZONE=...

gcloud compute instances create-with-container test \
--container-image=gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue \
--image-family=cos-stable \
--image-project=cos-cloud \
--machine-type=f1-micro \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

On the VM:

```sh
docker container ls --format="{{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}"
521d11ace93b    gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue
11ae194b354e    gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent:1.8.9

curl \
--silent \
--output /dev/null \
--write-out '%{response_code}' \
localhost:8080
200 # Success

# Matches `kuard` container
sudo journalctl --unit=konlet-startup
Starting a container with ID: 521d11ace93b...

# http-alt == 8080
sudo ss --tcp --listening --processes
Local Address:Port         Process                              
*:http-alt                 users:(("kuard",pid=893,fd=3))

# Using pid from ss command
ps aux | grep 893
893  /kuard
```

Comment: But isn't the point that Google is taking the image and not the container? I'm `docker push`ing my image to the Artifact Registry and using that to form my VM. The ports I exposed using `-p` were on a test container I created on my local machine--I'm not trying to pass that to the VM

Comment: I'll get the exact details for you in a moment, but yes, I confirmed that there was a container running on my VM using `docker ps`

Comment: My assumption is that the VM is creating a container around the image that I passed in--I want to customize how it's doing that

Comment: if that's not what's going on please correct me. obviously something I'm doing is wrong

Comment: You can do all those things. You don't need to `--publish` ports though because these equivalent `docker` command would be `docker run --net=host ...` and so your container's ports are bound automatically. If you need to run a different command and/or arguments, you can use the `--container-command` and `--container-arg` flags.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the terminal commands you're using? Don't worry about the MRP'ing the image--I can provide that--but I would appreciate seeing the full list of commands. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer with more details

Comment: Ok, so your instructions worked!